# Htaccess rewrite rule with 2 optional parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the page example.php with 2 optional parameters **name1** & **name2**.
The page also works with no parameters.

This is my rewrite rule for both parameters included, but this rule won't work for the page without parameters. How do I do. please?

```
RewriteRule ^(example)/([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)?$ $1.php?name1=$2&name2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Add another rewrite rule to the page without the parameters BEFORE this one, setting the flag to interrupt rules when it matches.

Comment: This way I told you?

Comment: Yes the way you said